# How do I make a div invisible unless "?added=1" is contained in the page URL?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to make a div invisible when someone goes to www.mysite.com/examplepage.php, but is visible when someone goes to www.mysite.com/example.php?added=1. Could someone be wonderful enough to explain this to me? The purpose of the div is give a message to users directed to the ?added=1 page - oddly enough something this useful is surprisingly hard to find instructions for. I'm a beginner, so if it's a simple thing to do I'd be really appreciative if someone gave me an example piece of code that would do this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your HTML/PHP template...

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['added']) AND $_GET['added'] == '1'): ?>
<div>
   ...
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Though it would be better to process the flag in some controller code and then set a flag, so you don't have to use the `isset()` and the `$_GET` directly in your view.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['added']) && $_GET['added'] == 1): ?>
     <div>thediv!</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Should get your started. The $_GET['added'] == 1 is optional in your case though.

```
<?php if (@$_GET['added'] == 1): ?>
     <div>thediv!</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Can also be used as a shorter version (although I would recommend just using only isset($_GET['added']) in your case, since I doubt you care about the =1 at the end).

Comment: You should mention what the `@` operator is, and why it's a bad idea. Also, user supplied GET params are always strings (or arrays of strings) so you may as well compare it to `'1'`.

Comment: @alex I fail to see how it's a bad idea in this case, it suppresses notifications if 'added' is not present and returns NULL instead. Nothing more, nothing less. It's simpler and that's often what PHP is about. But then again, in this case, isset($_GET['added']) is most likely sufficient.

Comment: Maybe it isn't so bad in *this* context, but it is in others.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct, but if you need to hide it but leave it in the source, something like this:

```
  <div <?php if ($_GET['added']==1)echo "style='display:none'"; ?>>
       hidden from the page, visible in view source.
  </div>
```

there are several reasons one want to leave it in the source, such as showing the div when certain button clicked.

Comment: A note though, on some setups yours will yield a notice unless you use @ or check the existance of 'added' first.